# best grouping combination to make every group have about the same number of elements

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization, combinatorics

I am solving a problem that I describe this way:

I have `N` sets, where the individual sets have `n_i` elements, `i=1,2,...N`. I want to divide the `N` sets into `P` groups, `P<N`. The goal is to make sure each group has about the same number of elements. Is there any existing algorithms for this problem? Thank you. PS: I cannot split a set itself.

Comment: possible PAQ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575086/algorithm-to-balance-variably-sized-items-into-roughly-balanced-sets

Comment: This is a variation of the subset sum problem, which is NP complete. So there's no algorithm that will produce the optimum answer in polynomial time. There is a pseudo-polynomial time DP, and you can adapt first/best fit heuristics.